# Reading HTML Page and creating a text file using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to read the IMDB list of top 50 movies. The code is working fine, but it stops reading at number 43 out of a list of 50.

```
public class FetchData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls053181721/").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
        Elements temp = doc.select("div.lister-item-content");

        int i=0;
        File file = new File("C:\\Demo Java\\IMDBList.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        for(Element movieList : temp) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i+" "+movieList.getElementsByTag("a").first().text());
            writer.write(+i+". "+movieList.getElementsByTag("a").first().text().toString()+"\n");

        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FetchData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html document you are loading through Jsoup does not load entirely, as the it exceeds the default maximum body size of 1MB. You need to increase the maximum allowed body size of the request in order to load the complete document.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls053181721/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/17.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .get();
```

Note: Adding `maxBodySize(0)` allows unlimited size.

Please Refer: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#maxBodySize-int-

Comment: some of the names on the list are showing in another language instead of English. Can you help me out with it?

Comment: I get all english text when I run your code. Will be able to help if you add specify your exact problem.